# ERROR Unable to run check class org.codehawk.plugin.java.checks.UnexploitedEncapsulation - UnexploitedEncapsulation on file

Tags: java, sonarqube

Small question regarding a Sonar analysis please.

I am running Sonarqube 9.x+ and I have this plugin configured in Maven:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Upon my Sonar execution, I am observing many of :

```
[ERROR] Unable to run check class org.codehawk.plugin.java.checks.UnexploitedEncapsulation - UnexploitedEncapsulation on file 'MyClass.java', To help improve the SonarSource Java Analyzer, please report this problem to SonarSource: see https://community.sonarsource.com/
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.codehawk.plugin.java.checks.UnexploitedEncapsulation.visitNode(UnexploitedEncapsulation.java:35)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge$IssuableSubscriptionVisitorsRunner.lambda$visit$5(VisitorsBridge.java:288)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge$IssuableSubscriptionVisitorsRunner.lambda$forEach$8(VisitorsBridge.java:304)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.runScanner(VisitorsBridge.java:156)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.access$200(VisitorsBridge.java:60)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge$IssuableSubscriptionVisitorsRunner.forEach(VisitorsBridge.java:304)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge$IssuableSubscriptionVisitorsRunner.visit(VisitorsBridge.java:290)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge$IssuableSubscriptionVisitorsRunner.visitChildren(VisitorsBridge.java:274)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge$IssuableSubscriptionVisitorsRunner.visit(VisitorsBridge.java:294)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge$IssuableSubscriptionVisitorsRunner.scanFile(VisitorsBridge.java:252)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.lambda$runScanner$0(VisitorsBridge.java:151)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.runScanner(VisitorsBridge.java:156)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.runScanner(VisitorsBridge.java:151)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:134)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:104)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.lambda$scan$1(JavaAstScanner.java:79)
    at org.sonar.java.model.JParserConfig$FileByFile.parse(JParserConfig.java:225)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:77)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scanAndMeasureTask(JavaFrontend.java:175)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scan(JavaFrontend.java:127)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSensor.execute(JavaSensor.java:109)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:79)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:382)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:378)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:375)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:347)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:186)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The very confusing part is: **org.codehawk.plugin.java.checks.UnexploitedEncapsulation**

I was wondering, what is the meaning of this stack trace, and how to resolve it please?

Thank you